# oracle 9i: ora-12705 invalid or unknown nls parameter value specified

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle9i, ora-12705

I have an Oracle 9i DB installed at remote IBM AIX server.
I want to connect to it using C# app (.Net)
Presently, I am able to connect to it using SQL Developer and SQLPlus from my machine.

But when I try to connect from Visual Studio App, using System.Data.OracleClient.

```
    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return "Data Source=<server address>;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;";
    }

    // This will open the connection and query the database
    private static void ConnectAndQuery()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
                Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
                                  connection.ConnectionString);

                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM demo";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["f1"];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

ORA-12705 invalid or unknown NLS parameter value specified

I have checked registry values for NLS it is already set to AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

Not sure how to handle this. Please suggest

Comment: UPDATE: I FOUND THE ANSWER...
I INSTALLED ODP.Net and it worked fine.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes for this problem are discussed [here on dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_error.htm).